# Java Classes Extend and Inheritance

Tags: java, class, inheritance, properties, constructor

```js
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at airline.booking.system.BookingFrame.savebookingButtonActionPerformed(BookingFrame.java:357)
 at airline.booking.system.BookingFrame.access$200(BookingFrame.java:21)
 at airline.booking.system.BookingFrame$3.actionPerformed(BookingFrame.java:102)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

So... been on this problem for the past 3 days. Its a bit hard to explain what I need.. but will try to be on point. The program "Used" to work fine. But I was told from my tutor to change my Booking class... My Booking class was Extending my Customer class to get other properties such as Name, Surname, Age etc... BUT (and it make sense) I was told to make my Customer a PROPERTY of the Booking Class and not Extending from it. Since I'm no longer Extending the Customer Class I'm getting errors in my code when trying to get the Name, Surname etc.. since I'm no longer Extending from the Customer class. How can I include a Customer as a Property and still get the Customer properties from the Customer Class. Thanks

```js
   private void loadCustomerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        Customer customerfile = null;
        try {

            final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("Customers/");
            int chooserOption = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (chooserOption == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(file)
                );

                customerfile = (Customer) in.readObject();

                custnameTF.setText(customerfile.getPersonName());
                custsurnameTF.setText(customerfile.getPersonSurname());
                custidTF.setText(customerfile.getPersonID());
                consnameTF.setText(customerfile.getConsultantname());
                conssurnameTF.setText(customerfile.getConsultantsurname());
                considTF.setText(customerfile.getConsulid());

                in.close();

            } else {
                throw new CancelException("Canceled Operation");
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error Loading File" + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error Loading Class");
        } catch (CancelException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Canceled Loading Customer",
                    "Canceled", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }                                            

    private void savebookingButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        Booking customerbooking = new Booking();
        Customer cust = customerbooking.getCustomer();

        try {
            if (custnameTF.getText().equals("")) {
                throw new EmptyField("Please Insert Customer");
            } else {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Bookings/" + custidTF.getText() + ".txt");
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

                cust.setPersonName((custnameTF.getText()));
                cust.setPersonSurname((custsurnameTF.getText()));
                cust.setPersonID((custidTF.getText()));
                cust.setConsultantname(consnameTF.getText());
                cust.setConsultantsurname((conssurnameTF.getText()));
                cust.setConsulid(considTF.getText());
                customerbooking.setFlightlocation(locationCB.getSelectedItem().toString());
                customerbooking.setFlighttime(timeCB.getSelectedItem().toString());
                customerbooking.setFlightfee(feeCB.getSelectedItem().toString());
                customerbooking.setCar(carRB.isSelected());
                customerbooking.setInsurance(insuranceRB.isSelected());

                oos.writeObject(customerbooking);
                oos.close();
                fos.close();

                custnameTF.setText("");
                custsurnameTF.setText("");
                custidTF.setText("");
                considTF.setText("");
                consnameTF.setText("");
                conssurnameTF.setText("");
                locationCB.setSelectedItem("");
                timeCB.setSelectedItem("");
                feeCB.setSelectedItem("");

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Booking was Saved Successfully!",
                        "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Booking could not be Saved!",
                    "Error!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } catch (EmptyField ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please Insert Customer",
                    "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }

        dispose();

    }                                                 

    private void custnameTFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    private void custidTFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void loadbookingButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        Booking bookingfile = null;
        Customer custfile = null;
        try {

            final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("Bookings/");
            int chooserOption = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (chooserOption == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(file)
                );

                bookingfile = (Booking) in.readObject();

                custnameTF.setText(custfile.getPersonName());
                custsurnameTF.setText(custfile.getPersonSurname());
                custidTF.setText(custfile.getPersonID());
                consnameTF.setText(custfile.getConsultantname());
                conssurnameTF.setText(custfile.getConsultantsurname());
                considTF.setText(custfile.getConsulid());
                locationCB.setSelectedItem(bookingfile.getFlightlocation());
                timeCB.setSelectedItem(bookingfile.getFlighttime());
                feeCB.setSelectedItem(bookingfile.getFlightfee());
                carRB.setSelected(bookingfile.getCar());
                insuranceRB.setSelected(bookingfile.getInsurance());

                in.close();

            } else {
                throw new CancelException("Canceled Operation");
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error Loading File" + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error Loading Class");
        } catch (CancelException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Canceled Loading Booking",
                    "Canceled", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }                                                 

    private void createCustbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        CustomerFrame nc = new CustomerFrame();
        nc.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: This is too much code. Just put a minimal code required to repro the problem and clearly specify what the exact error is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure that I clearly understand you. But try something like this:

```
Booking customerbooking = new Booking();
Customer cust = customerbooking.getCustomer();
cust.setPersonName((custnameTF.getText()));
cust.setPersonSurname((custsurnameTF.getText()));
```

You can't call methods of `Customer` from `Booking`. First you need to get reference to your `Customer` object.

You can't do that:

```
customerbooking.setPersonName((custnameTF.getText()));
customerbooking.setPersonSurname((custsurnameTF.getText()));
```

Comment: I added the Customer part but now Im getting an exception when trying to save a Booking file. 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Can you save your current code to Gist and give a link? Or just give new code block and full exception output. And why do you have two equal code blocks in your question?

Comment: And now add your exception output.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Exception was added at the top. Thanks

Comment: Is your class in `BookingFrame.java`? What is situated on 357 line?

Comment: No my class is separate. On line 357 I have :   cust.setPersonName((custnameTF.getText()));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87791/discussion-between-thestigger-and-luke-i).

Answer (score 0):

What your tutor wants is probably something like this. If not then please be more specific about the problem.

```
class Customer {
    private int someVal = 42;
   // lots of instance variables and methods
   public int getSomeVal() {
      return someVal;
   }
}

class Booking {
  Customer c;
  int fortytwo;
  // more variables
  public Booking() {}
  public Booking(Customer c) {
    this.c = c;
    fortytwo = c.getSomeVal();
    // more stuff
  }
  // more code
}
```

main:

```
Customer c = new Customer();
Booking b = new Booking(c);
```

With the Customer reference you can now access the Customer methods in your Booking class or whereever else you have a Customer Object.